# NullPointerException when trying find User using DAO

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, actionlistener, dao

I have a problem when trying find user using method `findUser`.
I create one windows "Login" to connect in my application and, when I click in "connect" button, is displayed these errors:

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.alstom.ems2.application.login.connectionActionPerformed(login.java:127)
    at com.alstom.ems2.application.login.access$100(login.java:16)
    at com.alstom.ems2.application.login$2.actionPerformed(login.java:61)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I'm using the NetBeans to create the application.

The code of application is create automatically, and he is here until the button part:

```
private void initComponents() {

        login = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        connection = new javax.swing.JButton();
        password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setIconImage(getIconImage());

        login.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 30));
        login.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                loginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Password");

        jLabel1.setText("User");

        connection.setText("Connect");
        connection.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(80, 25));
        connection.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                connectionActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
```

The connectionActionPerformed, of the button action.

```
private void connectionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    UserDAO u = null;
    User ut = null;

    ut = u.findUser(login.getText()); //error (login.java:127)

}
```

The method findUser at UserDAO

```
public User findUser(String login) {
    try{
        return  (User) em.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.login = '" +login+ "'").getSingleResult();
    }catch(NoResultException n){
        return null;
    }
    }
```

And the last one, to create the user at Data Base.

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   EntityManager em = Data.createEntityManager();

    try {
       UserDAO u = new UserDAO (em);
       User us = new User();

       us.setLogin("lol");
       us.setPassword("test");

       u.create(us);  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }        
 }
}
```

Thanks you.

Comment: what is the line login.java:127?

Comment: login.java:127 is: User ut = null;

Comment: no as Chris wrote I am realy sure that the line is 
ut = u.findUser(login.getText());

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, sorry.

Comment: When the time passes, be sure to mark the correct answer for future readers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UserDAO u = null;
User ut = null;

ut = u.findUser(login.getText()); //error
```

Your UserDAO object, u, is set to null. You will get a null pointer error because no instance of u exists yet.

Comment: But, in the class UserDAO:

Comment: yes now you get the NullPointer from (User) em.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.login = '" +login+ "'") If you call getSingleResult(); on a null value youre process will crash.(see my edited answer)

Comment: But, in the class UserDAO:

`public class UserDAO{
    private final EntityManager em;
    public UserDAO(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    public UserDAO  find(String login) {
        return  (User) em.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.login = '" +login+ "'").getSingleResult();
    }
}`

I can't instance of UserDAO if not create an EntityManager ...

Comment: Perhaps implementing a static "getUserDAOInstance()" factory method in your EntityManager class, and calling it from there?

Comment: I've create a class Data.java to create my Persistance Unit.
`public class Data {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");    
    public static EntityManager createEntityManager(){
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}`
Then where the method "getUserDAOInterface()" is created? I'm beginner, sorry.

Comment: You could include a method in data if you wanted. A static method that creates a new instance of UserDAO (from your EntityManagerFactory emf class) and returns that new object?

Comment: Can you give me one example? I really don't understand yet.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Sure. So You've created a class "Data". In Data, you've created a static EntityManagerFactory class, called emf. This is instantiation by the Pestistence.creatEntityManagerFactory() method. In a previous comment, you said you need an EntityManager to create an instance of a UserDAO object. Well now you have that EntityManager, so call the method in EntityManager to create a UserDAO object, and return the result.

Comment: Yes, I need an EntityManager to create an instance of UserDAO object because this will persist to create, remove,... in the Data Base.
`public class UserDAO {
    private final EntityManager em;
    
    public UserDAO(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }`
Ok... Now I have "em", representing the EntityManager, you said to create a
`private static getUserDAOInstance() {
   return this;
}`

Like that?
If it is not too much to ask, can you show me the code?

Comment: `private static getUserDAOInstance() { 
     return em.getDAOInstance(); // Or whatever the method is called.
}

Comment: If I create that, the EntityManager don't have this method getDAOInstance() then I can't call the method. Maybe I would create a new method in the class EntityManager "getDAOInstance()" ?

Comment: You said that you use the EntityManager to create a new instance of UserDAO. How do you do that?

Comment: Yes, I said that. See the code in below in the UserDAO
`private final EntityManager em;
 public UserDAO(EntityManager em) { this.em = em; }`
I create this because in the class UserDAO I need to persist the object in the Data Base with the methods create, remove, update...
See in the App class, I use the UserDAO to create a new User in the Data Base. And to find any user, I utilise the same class with the method findUser.

Comment: Riiiiiiight. in your code, where it says UserDAO u = null, you can replace that with UserDAO = new UserDAO(Data.createEntityManager());

Comment: Right, but every time when I call Data.createEntityManager(), is create a new Data Base ... Than this doens't work.

Comment: Right. So there only should ever be one EntityManager?

Comment: Yes, only for the UserDAO ( EntityManager em ), to create a object to persist the object User in the Data Base.

Comment: So then UserDAO needs to be a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class. it's a class that can only be created once. Read up on that and try to use that. :)

Answer (score 1):

that cannot work

```
UserDAO u = null;
User ut = null;

ut = u.findUser(login.getText()); //error
```

you declare u as null and then you call findUser. You have to initiate UserDAO:

```
UserDAO u = new UserDAO();
User ut = null;
ut = u.findUser(login.getText()); //error
```

Btw... You are absolutly sure that this will work?

```
(User) em.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.login = '" +login+ "'").getSingleResult();
```

Is there no need for "SELECT u FROM" ?

```
(User) em.createQuery("Select u FROM User u WHERE u.login = '" +login+ "'").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Yes, it's work ... `em.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.login = '" +login+ "'").getSingleResult();` .